# MySQL query takes too long and Apache hangs out

Tags: mysql, apache

I have a query that, some times, takes a lot of time to execute.

I know I have to tune that query and fix some MySQL problems, but, my question is other.

When this query is "locking" other queries in MySQL, the Apache web request that generated that query hangs out (that's normal), but prevents other web request to execute, since other web requests generates other SQL queries, but MySQL is "locked" with that first one.

How can I do to prevent this ? I would like that one slow SQL query of an apache request would not affect other queries of other web requests.

Comment: Possibly the resources are locked down by that query

Comment: Does that query use transactions, or table locking? What are query limits settings? Inspect result from `SHOW VARIABLES`

Comment: No, no transactions or table locking … just a "big" query with some joins (I know I have to fix that, but the problem is to prevent this "bad" query to lock other web apache requests) … What variables are about query limits ?